# Почему не работает аннотация @Order в spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

У меня имеется spring проект:

```
.
├── src/main/java/ua/lokha/springtest
│   ├── Bean1.java
│   ├── Bean2.java
│   ├── IBean.java
│   └── TestApplication.java
└── pom.xml
```

Классы `Bean1` и `Bean2` являются бинами и оба имплементируют интерфейс `IBean`. В этих бинах я сделал одинаковый init метод, который вывод в консоль сообщение:

```java
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }
```

Когда я запускаю проект, в лог выводится такой порядок загрузки бинов:

```
ua.lokha.springtest.Bean1
ua.lokha.springtest.Bean2
```

Я пробовал ставить аннотацию `@Order(1)` и `@Order(2)` в `Bean1` и `Bean2`, пробовал менять местами эту аннотацию. И это ничего не меняло, `Bean1` всегда загружается перед `Bean2`. Почему?

Я залил на github этот проект: https://github.com/lokha/spring-test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Order` служит для указания порядка в коллекциях. Например если у вас есть

```
@Autowired
private List<IBean> beans;
```

То элементы в списке `beans` буду согласно порядку `@Order`. Для управления же порядком загрузки бинов, когда Bean1 зависит от Bean2 следует использовать `@DependsOn`